# Try/Catch Keyboard Interrupt in Perl?

Tags: perl, signals

How can I catch a keyboard interrupt in Perl?

```
while(1) {
    try {
        print 1;
    } 
    catch KeyboardInterrupt {
        print 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be trying to write Python here.

"Keyboard interrupt", most likely means `SIGINT`. You can handle signals using the `%SIG` hash. For example:

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { print "Received SIGINT\n" };
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I am much more familiar with Python than Perl.